# По какой причине не работает планировщик задач Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

***Kernel.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Histori;
use DB;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $test=DB::table('history');
           $test ->delete();
        })->dailyAt('23:20');
    }
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

> Мне нужно чтобы в 23:20 каждый день чистилась таблица в БД (таблица
>   history)

Comment: Собственно а как вы Cron настроили?

Comment: ??  при вводе команды была ошибка (Системе не удается найти указанный путь.)

Comment: Я не знаю как вы настроили крон, и не могу понять что именно вы пытаетесь удалить?

Comment: Всмысли настроили Cron можно по точней про настройку

Comment: Есть команда cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 вы про  это

Comment: https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/scheduling

Comment: Как пример рабочая запись на одном из проектов `* * * * * php7.2 /home/r/***/domains/***/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`